# Making the FinishLocation of a Flow as the newly created Record

Tags: visual-workflow, visuaforce

I am creating a new record using Screen/Create Record elements of a Flow. I am starting that Flow with a customized New button. I am now attempting to make the FinishLocation as the newly created record. Here is the VF page which I am referring to with the New button in order to kick off the Flow :

```xml
<apex:page standardcontroller="Vendor_Profile__c" Extensions="New_Vendor_With_Flow_Controller2">
<flow:interview interview="{!myFlow}" name="New_Vendor_Profile" finishlocation="{!finishlocation}"/>
</apex:page>
```

and the class which is the Extension is this :

```
public class New_Vendor_With_Flow_Controller2 {

    public New_Vendor_With_Flow_Controller2(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }


public flow.interview.New_Vendor_Profile myflow {get;set;}

    public New_Vendor_With_Flow_Controller2() {
    }
    
    public String getendID() {
        
        if (myflow !=null) return myflow.VarRecordID;
        else return 'home/home.jsp';
        }
       
    public PageReference getFinishLocation() {
        System.debug('VarRecordID ########'+ myflow.VarRecordID); 
        PageReference endlocation = new PageReference('/' + getendID());
        return endlocation;
        }
}
```

I am attempting to use the VarRecordID variable which I set in the Create Record element in the Page Reference.

I don't think I need to set a FinishLocation in the VF page, do I ? If I set that it will only go to that spot at the end of the Flow. I don't think I can refer to the VarRecordID variable in the FinishLocation so I didn't set one.
Anyone have any suggestions on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to set the finishLocation in the visualforce page, you will also need a screen after the record is created, this screen causes a refresh of the visualforce page which will then give the finishLocation access to the variable.

Comment: – thanks very much for your input. I have made some changes to the code, both on the VF page and the controller. Interesting enough I'm getting an error: “Invalid Page Redirection–the page you attempted to access has been blocked to a redirection to an outside website”. I don’t know how that’s happening. I’m wondering if anything has to do with the fact that I'm using my controller as an Extension of a standard controller instead of simply referring to it as the Controller in the VF page.I would do that, but then I don’t have the VF page as an option when customizing the New button.

Comment: @Zoom_v take a look at this q/a for a possible solution to that issue http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4041/difference-between-controller-and-extensions

Comment: Thank you @Jenny -That was a great post.But I can't say I have any more of any of whether or not my problems are being caused by me using an Extnsion instead of a Custom Contrllr.They mention wizard-like behavior as one of the times a Custom would be necessary.That is what I'm doing here with the Screen element of a Flow.I don't know how to use a Custom in a VF page in a way which would allow me to reference it for a customized New button-like I do if I use a Standrd cntrller referring to the object.Do you know what I need to write into a Custom to make it available for a customized button?

Comment: @Zoom_v why do you need to use a controller? I would probably just change it to an extension.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. It is an extension already. I'm using a Standard Controller so the VF page will show up as an option when I am customizing the New button.

Comment: @Zoom_v sorry misunderstood, you can definitely use an extension no need to use a controller. Initially I thought you had it set up as a controller. Did you add a screen after the record is created?

Comment: No - I didn't add a screen. I'll do that. What should be in the Screen ? Should there be some kind of Finish button ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30359/discussion-between-jenny-b-and-zoom-v).

Comment: As a reference to anybody who reads this : Jenny's suggestion of the final Screen/Finish button is exactly what did it ! Don't forget your final Screen folks !