# Visualforce page with custom conroller not available for button

Tags: visualforce, controller, list, button

I found many related articles on this, but the details of my situation don't seem to line up with the common queries.

I have a VF Page that I want to pull information from via the current account. So, the controller is an Apex class that gets all of that.

When I try to use this VF Page for the button (trying both Detail and List Button), it does not appear.

I tried:
  `StandardListController = "AccountRenewal"` (that's the .apxc)
and get:

> 'Unsupported attribute standardListController in in AccountRenewal at line 1'

I tried:
  `recordSetVar='accountrenewal'`
and get:

> No standard controller was specified - recordSetVar cannot be used.

I try then adding `StandardController="AccountRenewal"` alongside that to appease it, but since that's my apex class, not a standard controller, it says it does not exist.

Suggestions?

Comment: haha, for Butter. Button*

Comment: StandardController should be sobject name (Account in your case). In that scenario, AccountRenewal should be an extension (extensions tag for apex page)

Comment: I tried this, too. When I do StandardController = "Account", I get...Line 0 Unknown property 'AccountStandardController.doingImportObjects'. I did a quick search on the page, that whole clump of text is nowhere on the page, but this error is persistent...

Comment: so, did you add *both* standardController and extension to the page?

Comment: @kurunve Extension only. The extension should inherit the standard controller so long as that's set in the class.

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis I am glad you can understand what he's asking for here... I'm looking at this and can't understand what he's really trying to do

Comment: @Griffin how do you know? that was question to author. And in case if you have VF page, you need to specify optionally Or controller or StandardController and optionally extension if one of previous is specified

Comment: @kurunve I added both standardController and extensions=

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis I read it too fast and thought it said "do you add" instead of "did you add".

Answer (score 5):

Recommended reading: [Difference between controller and extensions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4041/difference-between-controller-and-extensions)

Here you are working on writing a `Controller Extension`. You add this `Apex Class` to your page via the `extensions` attribute on the `<apex:page>` [tag](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm).

---

If you want to enable a **<kbd>Detail Button</kbd>** on `Account`, your `Visualforce Page` must use the `standardController` attribute.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountRenewal">
```

Then your class needs a constructor that accepts this `standardController` as a parameter.

```
public with sharing class AccountRenewal
{
    public AccountRenewal(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        // extension constructor logic
    }
}
```

---

If you want instead to enable a **<kbd>List Button</kbd>** on `Account`, your `Visualforce Page` must use the `recordSetVar` attribute in addition to the `standardController` attribute.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts" extensions="AccountRenewal">
```

Then your class needs a constructor that accepts `standardSetController` as a parameter.

```
public with sharing class AccountRenewal
{
    public AccountRenewal(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller)
    {
        // extension constructor logic
    }
}
```

Comment: When I did the latter -- for List Button -- the errors went away, but still N/A when trying to select the VF Page. It is set as available in setup. The first portion -- for Detail -- gave a wonky error I don't feel is even worth posting...

Comment: If you want the button to appear when you are looking at the *detail* page for one record, you need a `Detail Button`. Does your `Apex Class` have the right constructor defined?

Comment: My apex class has this:   public AccountRenewal(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller){
        setupObjects();
    }

Comment: You need to accept `ApexPages.StandardController` for a `Detail Button`. It's a different class than `ApexPages.StandardSetController`, which you use for a `List Button`. Be careful with your types.

Comment: what do you mean by this? what exactly do I do?

Comment: I did -- I'm in the same position. For more context, the precise error I got when trying the Detail option is: common.apex.runtime.bytecode.BytecodeApexObjectType cannot be cast to common.apex.runtime.impl.ApexType

Comment: As for List option, no errors, but it doesn't show up as a VF Page option when setting up the button

Comment: You can only use the list one with a ***List Button***. As for the error...perhaps it has something to do with this [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008bIkAAI)? Try saving through other methods, like editing the page/class by going to `Setup` > `Develop` > `<Visualforce Pages|Apex Classes>`.

Comment: I made sure to select List rather than Detail....anything else I'm doing wrong?