# View state does not appear on pages using Standard controllers?

Tags: visualforce, standardcontroller, viewstate

I am looking into 'View State Limit exceeded' error and want to display the View state information using the development mode footer. For my user, I have enabled both *Development Mode* and *Show View State in Development Mode*.

At the moment, I cannot get the View State to appear. The page does contain `<apex:form>` tags but is using a *standardController*.

By using a Standard Controller, does this mean I cannot get the View State information I need?

> Since the view state is linked to form data, the View State tab only appears if your page contains an `<apex:form>` tag. In addition, the View State tab displays only on pages using custom controllers or controller extensions. [Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_tools_edit_toolbar.htm)

Does anyone know any other way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the message states is that you need some custom `Apex` code for the page to bother serializing the `View State` and sending it to the server. There are two ways to do so.

1. Use a standard controller with a controller extension.
2. Use a custom controller.

If you are using a `StandardController` already, you would write an `Extension`. The `Visualforce Developer Guide` has a great article on [Building a Controller Extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm). In essence, you need to write a class that accepts the `StandardController` as a parameter in its constructor, then add it to the `extensions` property of your `<apex:page>` tag.

**Extension**

```
public with sharing class MyExtension
{
    public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        // constructor logic if necessary
    }
}
```

**Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="..." extensions="MyExtension">
    <!-- additional markup -->
</apex:page>
```

Note that the property is plural. You can add more than one extension to a page.

I also highly recommend you read **[Difference between controller and extensions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4041/difference-between-controller-and-extensions/4055#4055)**. It's one of the better answers anywhere on this forum.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have created an extension class and am adding it to my page. I am also certain at this point I should be able to  see the View State.

Comment: Are you aware of any known issues based on browsers preventing the View State?

Comment: I'm not even sure that's technically possible. Certainly not without some hack-y browser extensions.