# Unable To Cover StandardSetController.getSelected Loop

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, standardsetcontroller

I cant seem to figure out why the creation of this custom object is not getting hit by my test class. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Here is the test class:

```
@isTest
public class TestCreateReviewsController {
    @isTest
    private static void init(){

        Account testAccount = new Account(name='Test Company Name');
        insert testAccount;
        Case ca = new Case(Subject='Test Controller Acct Case');
        ca.AccountId = testAccount.Id;
        insert ca;

        List<Case> cases = new List<Case>();
        cases.add([ Select Id From Case Where Id = : ca.Id ]);

        // start the test execution context
        Test.startTest();

        // load the page       
        PageReference pageRef = Page.MassCreateCaseReview;
        pageRef.getParameters().put('Id',ca.Id);
        Test.setCurrentPageReference(pageRef);

        //load the controller extension
        CreateReviewsController crc = new CreateReviewsController(new ApexPages.StandardSetController( cases ));

        crc.createReviews();
        List<Case_Review__c> crIds = new List<Case_Review__c>();
        for(Case cs : cases){
            Case_Review__c crS = new Case_Review__c();
            crS.Case__c = cs.Id;
            crIds.add(crS);
        }
        insert crIds;
        crc.getMyReviews();

        Test.stopTest();




    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never set the selected records. Break out your controller and extension constructors so you can do so.

```
ApexPages.StandardSetController controller = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(cases);
controller.setSelected(cases);
CreateReviewsController extension = new CreateReviewsController(controller);
```

Also, you can simplify a lot of your setup related to `cases` by just constructing and inserting the list. No need to query or call `List.add` anywhere.

```
List<Case> cases = new List<Case> { new Case(Subject='...', AccountId=account.Id) };
insert cases;
```

One more thing: it's always worth reading [Difference between controller and extensions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4041/difference-between-controller-and-extensions)!

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Comment: Awesome! I knew it was setting the selected cases somewhere. Thank you so much.