# Extension Test: Constructor not defined: [<Extension-Name>].<Constructor>(ApexPages.StandardController)

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, standardcontroller, extension

I tried to write a Testclass for an Extension that is supposed to handle a replacement for a creation-page.

TestClass:

```
@isTest
public class VisualforcePageExtTest{
    static testMethod void validateVfPInit(){

        PageReference tpageRef = Page.VisualforcePageName;
        Test.setCurrentPage(tpageRef);

        //Testdata creation
        Account testAcc = new Account(Name = 'TestAccount', ao_Invoice_Type__c = 'Test', ax_lob__c = 'Test');
        insert testAcc;
        CustomObject testObj = new CustomObject (Name = 'TestName', 
                                                   account__c = testAcc.ID);
        insert testObj;

        Test.startTest();

        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(testObj);            
        VisualforcePageExt scExt = new VisualforcePageExt(sc);

        // POSITIV TESTS
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

I do however get the error

> "Constructor not defined: [VisualforcePageExt].(ApexPages.StandardController)"

on the following line:

```
VisualforcePageExt scExt = new VisualforcePageExt(sc);
```

I also tried to use StandardSetController instead but got the error

> "Constructor not defined: [ApexPages.StandardSetController].(CustomObject)"

The Extension:

```
public class VisualforcePageExt{

    private final CustomObject header = new CustomObject();
    public String accId = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('accid');

    public VisualforcePageExt(ApexPages.StandardSetController stdController) {
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()) stdController.addFields(new List<String>{'Account__c','Drucken__c','Kundennummer__c','SV_ort_f_r_FZBW__c','Zeilen_zentrieren__c','Erfasste_Zeilen__c','Land_Code__c','TP_Kopf_1__c','TP_Kopf_2__c','TP_Kopf_3__c','TP_Kopf_4__c','TP_Kopf_5__c','TP_Kopf_6__c','Schrift_1__c','Schrift_2__c','Schrift_3__c','Schrift_4__c','Schrift_5__c','Schrift_6__c','Erstellungsdatum_AS400__c'});
    }
    public CustomObject getHeader(){
        if(System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('accid') != null){
            Account masterAcc = [SELECT BillingStreet, BillingCity, Phone FROM Account Where Id = :accId LIMIT 1];
            System.debug('Street:' + masterAcc.BillingStreet +', '+ masterAcc.BillingCity);
            header.Account__c = accId;
            header.TP_Kopf_3__c = masterAcc.BillingStreet + ', ' + masterAcc.BillingCity;
            header.TP_Kopf_4__c = masterAcc.Phone;
            header.Zeilen_zentrieren__c = true;
        }
        return header;
    }
    public PageReference save(){
        insert header;
        PageReference pg = new PageReference('/'+header.Id);
        return pg;
    }

    public PageReference redirectExistingHeader() {
        TP_Header__c[] headCount = [SELECT Name FROM TP_Header__c WHERE Account__c = :accId LIMIT 1];     
        System.Debug('Headcount:' + headCount.size());
        if(headCount.size()>0){
            PageReference pg = new PageReference('/'+headCount[0].id);
            pg.setRedirect(true);
            return pg;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Added Extension

Comment: Can we see your actual extension constructors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not defined any constructors explicitly, then the empty constructor is implicitly defined, and no other constructors are allowed. That would also really make your `Apex` a Controller more than an Extension. Worth a read: [Difference between controller and extensions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/4041/2995)

Basically, these two classes are the same as far as constructors go:

```
public class MyController { }

// above is same as below

public class MyController
{
    public MyController() { /*empty constructor*/ }
}
```

If you do indeed want to write an *extension*, you need to make sure you explicitly define the appropriate constructor. If you are trying to create a Detail Button/link, use `StandardController`. If you are trying to create a List Button, use `StandardSetController`:

```
public class MyExtension
{
    public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Solved the problem. The Standard Construter is now defined as follows: 
`ApexPages.StandardSetController sc = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(new List<TP_Header__c> {testHeader});`

The StandardSetController was expecting a List.