# Pagination with the CustomController is not working?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am developing Pagination code, but facing the below error:

```
Unknown constructor 'AccountDisplatRecClsPagination.AccountDisplatRecClsPagination(AccountDisplatRecCls controller)'
```

**AccountDisplatRecCls**

```
public class AccountDisplatRecCls {
    public List<Account> getAccounts(){
        List<Account> accList = [select Id, Name, AccountNumber from Account];
        return accList;
    }

    public List<Contact> getContacts(){
        List<Contact> conList = [select id, FirstName, LastName, Email from Contact];
        return conList;
    }
}
```

**AccountDisplatRecClsPagination**

```
public class AccountDisplatRecClsPagination {
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController con{get; set;}

    public AccountDisplatRecClsPagination(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller){
        this.con = controller;
        this.con.setPageSize(5);
    }

    //Boolean to check if there are more records after the present displaying records
    public Boolean hasNext {
        get{
            return con.getHasNext();
        }
        set;
    } 
    //Boolean to check if there are more records before the present displaying records
    public Boolean hasPrevious {
        get{
            return con.getHasPrevious();
        }
        set;
    } 
    //Page number of the current displaying records
    public Integer pageNumber {
        get {
            return con.getPageNumber();
        }
        set;
    }
    //Returns the previous page of records
    public void previous() {
        con.previous();
    } 

    //Returns the next page of records
    public void next(){
        con.next();
    }
}
```

**VFPage**

```
<apex:page controller="AccountDisplatRecCls" extensions="AccountDisplatRecClsPagination">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Account Records">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Accounts}" var="acc">
                <apex:column value="{!acc.Name}" />
                <apex:column value="{!acc.accountNumber}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlock title="Contacts Details">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Contacts}" var="con">
                <apex:column value="{!con.FirstName}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!con.LastName}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!con.Email}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock> 

         <apex:pageBlockSection title="Page Navigation">
                <apex:panelGrid columns="5">
                    Total Records Found: <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(Con.resultSize==10000,true,false)}">10000 
                    +</apex:outputText><apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(Con.resultSize < 10000,true,false)}">
                    {!Con.resultSize}</apex:outputText>

                    <apex:commandLink action="{!Previous}" title="Previous Page" value="Previous Page" rendered="{!Con.HasPrevious}"/>
                    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="pShowLess noLink" style="color:grey" rendered="{!NOT(Con.HasPrevious)}">Previous Page</apex:outputPanel>         
                    &nbsp;({!IF(Con.PageNumber == 1,1,((Con.PageNumber -1) * Con.PageSize)+1)}-{!IF(Con.resultSize < Con.PageSize,Con.resultSize,Con.PageNumber * Con.pageSize)})&nbsp;
                    <apex:commandLink title="Next Page" value="Next Page" rendered="{!Con.HasNext}" action="{!Next}"/>&nbsp;
                </apex:panelGrid>       
            </apex:pageBlockSection> 
       </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue like below. Its working fine.

**AccountDisplatRecCls**

```
public class AccountDisplatRecCls {

    public ApexPages.StandardSetController con {
        get {
            if(con == null) {
                String query = 'select Id, Name, AccountNumber from Account';
                con = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(query));
                // sets the number of records in each page set
                con.setPageSize(5);
            }
            return con;
        }
        set;
    }

    public List<Account> getAccounts(){
        return con.getRecords();
    }

    // indicates whether there are more records after the current page set.
    public Boolean hasNext {
        get {
            return con.getHasNext();
        }
        set;
    }

    // indicates whether there are more records before the current page set.
    public Boolean hasPrevious {
        get {
            return con.getHasPrevious();
        }
        set;
    }

    // returns the page number of the current page set
    public Integer pageNumber {
        get {
            return con.getPageNumber();
        }
        set;
    }

    // returns the first page of records
     public void first() {
         con.first();
     }

     // returns the last page of records
     public void last() {
         con.last();
     }

     // returns the previous page of records
     public void previous() {
         con.previous();
     }

     // returns the next page of records
     public void next() {
         con.next();
     }

     // returns the PageReference of the original page, if known, or the home page.
     public void cancel() {
         con.cancel();
     }
}
```

**AccountDisplatRecClsVFPage**

```
<apex:page controller="AccountDisplatRecCls">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Account Records">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Accounts}" var="acc">
                <apex:column value="{!acc.Name}" />
                <apex:column value="{!acc.accountNumber}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlock>
         <apex:pageBlockSection title="Page Navigation">
                <apex:panelGrid columns="5">
                    Total Records Found: <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(Con.resultSize==10000,true,false)}">10000 
                    +</apex:outputText><apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(Con.resultSize < 10000,true,false)}">
                    {!Con.resultSize}</apex:outputText>

                    <apex:commandLink action="{!Previous}" title="Previous Page" value="Previous Page" rendered="{!Con.HasPrevious}"/>
                    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="pShowLess noLink" style="color:grey" rendered="{!NOT(Con.HasPrevious)}">Previous Page</apex:outputPanel>         
                    &nbsp;({!IF(Con.PageNumber == 1,1,((Con.PageNumber -1) * Con.PageSize)+1)}-{!IF(Con.resultSize < Con.PageSize,Con.resultSize,Con.PageNumber * Con.pageSize)})&nbsp;
                    <apex:commandLink title="Next Page" value="Next Page" rendered="{!Con.HasNext}" action="{!Next}"/>&nbsp;
                </apex:panelGrid>       
            </apex:pageBlockSection> 
          </apex:pageBlock>
       </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Here is the result**

[image]

Comment: hasNext, hasPrevious, pageNumber, first, last, previous, next, and cancel are all unnecessary here, and getAccounts isn't particularly necessary either.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to some changes in VF to use those methods.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is initially here:

```
<apex:page 
    controller="AccountDisplatRecCls" 
    extensions="AccountDisplatRecClsPagination">
```

Whenever you use a custom controller, any extension classes must have a constructor that accepts the custom controller class as a parameter:

```
public class AccountDisplatRecClsPagination {
    public AccountDisplatRecClsPagination(AccountDisplatRecCls controller) {
        // Do stuff here
    }
    // More code here
}
```

If you want to use the out-of-the-box StandardSetController, you'd have to change your page as follows:

```
<apex:page 
    standardController="Account" 
    recordSetVar="accounts"
    extensions="AccountDisplatRecClsPagination">
```

Or, alternatively, change your AccountDisplatRecClsPagination class:

```
public class AccountDisplatRecClsPagination {
    ApexPages.StandardSetController con { get; set; }
    public AccountDisplatRecClsPagination(AccountDisplatRecCls controller) {
        con = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(controller.getAccounts());

        // Do stuff here
    }
    // More code here
}
```

Assuming that was your intent. I'm honestly not entirely sure why you'd want to split up your logic this way, since you could have simply included the StandardSetController in your original class:

```
public class AccountDisplatRecCls {
    ApexPages.StandardSetController con { get; set; }
    public AccountDisplatRecCls() {
        con = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(
            Database.getQueryLocator(
                [SELECT Name, AccountNumber FROM Account]
            )
        );
    }
    // More code here
}
```

Which you could have then accessed in your page directly:

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!con.Previous}" title="Previous Page" value="Previous Page" rendered="{!Con.HasPrevious}"/>
```

Comment: This sort of answer is where I feel the terminology [difference between controllers and extensions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/4041/2995) can make things much more clear. That first section really tripped me up.

Comment: @AdrianLarson yeah, I cleaned up the wording a bit.

Comment: You could still make it more universal. Standard controllers have the same design, so it's not specific to custom controllers.